# How do I add the Peoplesoft identifier to my autonomous database (shared)

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft, oracle-autonomous-db

I was told that some settings in autonomous are special for Peoplesoft and that I need some kind of identifier. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you provision ADB-S instance, log an SR detailing the following information:

PRODUCT: Autonomous Database on Shared Infrastructure
ABSTRACT/SUMMARY: PSFT on ADBS: please set PeopleSoft DB identifier

In the SR, please include:

1. Region (Data Center location)
2. Tenancy name and OCID
3. Autonomous DB name and OCID
4. Request to set init.ora paramaeter: _unnest_subquery=false

Cloud Ops will then make the change for your environment(s).

Reference:
MOS Note: 2765965.1 - Tech Update – PeopleSoft Extends Support for Oracle Autonomous Database